# DynamoDB GSI vs LSI for Numerical fields

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I am going through a DynamoDb udemy course and came across the following example
for leaderboard design,

[image: Base Table]

Now, to easily fetch the top scores (or the top 10 in leaderboard),
the course goes on to do the following

**GSI**

| PK | SK | player |
| --- | --- | --- |
| top_score | 150 | player#2 |
| top_score | 200 | player#1 |
| top_score | 250 | player#3 |

Now, this works quite well for the instructor in the course,
however, if player#2 now scores 50 more, then the primary key(PK + SK)
wont be unique (top_score + 200) will point to two records.

I then think, that numerical fields will never make sense in a
GSI, unless they are IDs.

Even if we make the score field unique by appending player_id along
with score, that will need the score field to be string, rather than
numerical, and then lexicographical order will be followed and not the
numerical ordering.

From AWS Dynamo docs regarding [GSI vs LSI in general](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general.html#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20you%20should%20use%20global%20secondary%20indexes%20rather%20than%20local%20secondary%20indexes) :

> In general, you should use global secondary indexes rather than local secondary indexes. The exception is when you need strong consistency in your query results, which a local secondary index can provide but a global secondary index cannot (global secondary index queries only support eventual consistency).

I think this is a clear case of using LSI (even
though the problem I just described in not related to consistency),
use LSI on the total_score attribute.

Am I right, or is there a way to actually use GSI for this ?

**Edit:**

The only thing I can think of is to pad sufficient 0s in scores,
and append player_id at the end

Like this,

| PK | SK |
| --- | --- |
| top_score | 000150#2 |
| top_score | 000200#1 |
| top_score | 000250#3 |

Comment: The base table in rendering perfectly in the editor preview, but not here, checking !  
Edit: Changed to snap for the base table

Comment: GSIs do not need to be unique.  It's perfectly acceptable to have GSIs that share the same PK/SK pattern.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan just to confirm, two GSI records can have the same PK AND SK ?

Comment: @SethGeoghegan You are right, I just checked, it works.